# how to pass argument from directive to directive

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-directive

I have two directive and I want to pass argument from one directive to another directive.

**Sample:**

Directive1:-

```
app.directive('myDirective1', [function () {
    return {
        restrict    : 'E',
        templateUrl : 'templates/myDirective1.html',
        link        : function (scope, elem, attr) {
            scope.items = 'myPara';
        }
}]);
```

Directive2:-

```
app.directive('myDirective2', [function () {
    return {
        restrict    : 'E',
        templateUrl : 'templates/myDirective2.html',
        scope       : {
            items : '='
        }
        link        : function (scope, elem, attr) {
            //here i want 'myPara'
        }
}]);
```

Html:-

```
<my-directive1 items="items">
  <my-directive2></my-directive2>
</my-directive1>
```

In the above example, when i change the value of `scope.items` in Directive1, it should be reflect on directive2 isolated scope(items). Now i can't get the value in Directive2. Can any one help me. Thanks.

Comment: You can also use event broadcasting if its a one-way communication. Else services.

Comment: @Ali Gajani, I have used the `broadcast` and its working fine. thanks!..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a service that you inject in both directives..

```
app.service('myService',function(){ return {myPara : undefined}})
```

Now add this service to your both directives and use the myPara like `myService.myPara = bla`
because the service is a singleton you will have the same instance in both your directives.

directive1:

```
app.directive('myDirective1', ['myService',function (myService) {
return {
    restrict    : 'E',
    templateUrl : 'templates/myDirective1.html',
    link        : function (scope, elem, attr) {
        scope.items = myService.myPara;
    }
}]);
```

directive2

```
app.directive('myDirective2', ['myService',function (myService) {
return {
    restrict    : 'E',
    templateUrl : 'templates/myDirective2.html',
    scope       : {
        items : '='
    }
    link        : function (scope, elem, attr) {
        //here i want 'myPara'
        myService.myPara // Here is your myPara
    }
}]);
```